# query posts with selected post ids first

Tags: posts, wp-query, order

Is there a way I can get most recent posts with a couple of posts I specify by post ID listed first?

According the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters), the `order` and `orderby` parameters may be passed as an array, so in theory I'm wondering if this could be possible.

In MySQL query terms, it would essentially produce a result like

```sql
SELECT * FROM wp_posts ORDER BY ID=12345 desc, ID=12543 desc, post_date desc
```

where it returns post 12345, then 12543, then the rest ordered newest first.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible to do this in a single query in Wordpress. You could potentially split it into two like below:

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;

// Get posts by selected post ids
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__in'       => [12345,12543],
    'orderby'        => 'post__in'
);
$myposts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li>
    <?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();

// Get latest posts excluding selected post ids
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'exclude'        => [12345,12543]
);

$myposts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li>
    <?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
```